# Laravel Mix extract all vue component css to single app.css

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I use `Laravel Mix` to compile and extract component css to single file such as `app.css`. For example I have a component like this:

```
<template>
   <div class="text">  </div>
<template>
...
<style>
   .text{ color: red; }
</style>
```

In `webpack.mix.js` is:

```
mix.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery','window.$'],
    quill: ['window.Quill','Quill']
});

mix.options({
    extractVueStyles: 'public/css/app.css',
});

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sourceMaps()
    .version();
```

and I put this code in `master..blade.php`

```php
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url(mix('/css/app.css')) }}">
```

But `app.css` is **empty** and my component css put in `html>head` as inline style:

```html
<html>
<head>
   ...
   <style>
         .text{ color: red; }
   </style>
</head>
...
</html>
```

What should I do to extract and put all component css in `app.css`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it puts the CSS of a .vue file in the app.js file. Since each of the styles are only localised to that specific component.

Comment: Can you show what's in the terminal after run command?